# OpenGL in C language add another object

Tags: c, opengl, visual-studio-2017, opengl-compat

I need help adding another object to my "drawing".
With the help of my college teacher code with Google I was able to create a face shape.

[image]

I want to add a smile to the face
What to add another shape to the drawing?

I tried to append to the void `face()` something like:

```c
glVertex2f(100, 125);
glVertex2f(400, 125);
```

This is the code in C language:

```c
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float  counter = 200;
static GLfloat spin = 0.0;
static GLfloat R = 0.2;
static GLfloat G = 0.9;
static GLfloat B = 0.8;
float carx = 500, cary = 50, fr = 0, fl = 0, fo = 0, fu = 0, mx = 0, my = 0;
void initOpenGl()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.8, 0); //Background Color
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, 1500, 0, 500);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void eye(int x, int y)
{
    float th;
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {

        th = i * (3.1416 / 180);
        glVertex2f(x + 25 * cos(th), y + 20 * sin(th));
    }
    glEnd();
}


void face()
{
    glLoadIdentity();//Bottom Par
    counter = counter - 0.03;
    if (fr > 0)
        carx += fr;
    if (fl > 0)
        carx -= fl;
    if (fu > 0)
        cary += fu;
    if (fo > 0)
        cary -= fo;
    if (mx > 0)
        carx += mx;
    if (my > 0)
        carx -= my;

    glTranslated(carx, cary, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);   //Top Part
    glVertex2f(100, 125);
    glVertex2f(400, 125);
    glVertex2f(400, 300);
    glVertex2f(100, 300);


    glEnd();
    eye(165, 230);
    eye(315, 230);



}

}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0.9, 0.33); //Push and pop matrix for separating circle object from Background
    face();
    pa();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}
void mouse(int button)
{
    switch (button) {
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON: mx = 0.3;
        break;
    case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:my = 0.2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
void keyFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {

    case 'w': fu = 0.3, fo = 0, fr = 0, fl = 0;
        break;

    case 's': fu = 0, fo = 0.2, fr = 0, fl = 0;
        break;
    case 'a': fu = 0.01, fo = 0, fr = 0, fl = 0.2;
        break;
    case 'd': fu = 0.01, fo = 0, fr = 0.2, fl = 0;
        break;
    case 'z': fu = 0, fo = 0.2, fr = 0, fl = 0.2;
        break;
    case 'c': fu = 0, fo = 0.2, fr = 0.2, fl = 0;
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }
    glutPostOverlayRedisplay();

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1500, 700);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Shai Goldenebrg");
    initOpenGl();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyFunc);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smiling mouth is a [Concave polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon). I recommend to use a [`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) to generate the mouth. e.g:

```c
void mouth(int x, int y)
{
    float th, s, c;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 240; i < 300; i++)
    {
        th = i * (3.1416 / 180);
        c = cos(th);
        s = sin(th);
        glVertex2f(x +  90 * cos(th), y + 100 +  90 * sin(th));
        glVertex2f(x + 110 * cos(th), y + 100 + 110 * sin(th));
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

```c
void face()
{
    // [...]

    eye(165, 230);
    eye(315, 230);
    mouth(240, 150);
}
```

[image]